# Asynchronous Machine SI Units variables

Tags: matlab, simulink

What are SM.* variables inside the simulink Asynchronous Machine subsystem block? Where I can see their description?

Answer (score 0):

Everything is described in great detail in the [documentation](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/physmod/sps/powersys/ref/asynchronousmachine.html) for the Asynchronous Machine block. You can access it by clicking on the "Help" button in the Block Parameters dialog window.

Comment: I've not found anything about SM structure there. I am looking for SM.R*inv(L) matrix structure because I need to edit it.

Comment: There is no SM structure in the block parameters. There may be something under the mask, but this is undocumented and not for the user to change. You should leave it alone.